# What does a table way to small for the screen create a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

## [Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73FHq/)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A1</td>
                <td>B1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A2</td>
                <td>B2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

As you can see in the demo, it causes horizontal scrollbars. Is there any way to get rid of this, other than using `javascript`?

Comment: `overflow: none` would be one option. Btw, the problem is that the `div` takes the full width of the page and is then shifted by 100px to the right. The div is not resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of left maybe try

```
margin-left: 100px;
```